# JB Email Audience Entry - Stuck on 'Paused'

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I created different pathways with an Email Audience Entry coming from data extensions, each interacting with a Query. I get this from the Automation Status: *'Paused'*

[image: Entry Event]
Except all my automation journeys linked to the JB pathways are running daily and as it can be seen, they are set to never end and they are active and not paused.

[image: Automation]

My entry result are growing in the JB pathway but none of it is actually getting in the pathway (because it's 'PAUSED'?). I'm kind of confused on what I didn't set right.

Adding that my current pathways has been stuck on the same data for a few days now due to that.

Comment: Just to confirm - the Journey is active and running right?

Comment: Yes my Journey's Status is 'Running' however when I click on it to get the detailed pathway, I get the Automation Status 'Paused' (first image in my previous post) but all mu automation for my Journeys are active and set. I do not get if this is normal or not.

Comment: are you using an automation that could've been paused by the system, due to a potential failure?

Comment: Not even, my automations are all like the second image, schedule are active and they repeat daily and end never... All of them are completed with no error or failure.